# How can I repair leaky windows/doors?

Tags: doors, windows, leak

I have a big window above the entrance double door.  Whenever it rains against the window I find the leaks at the top of the window corner, at the bottom of the window and in my cold room which is below the door.

Any suggestions on how to fix them?

Comment: Have you inspected it? Noticed any gaps, cracks, etc?

Comment: What kind of window is it? Is it single pane glass or dual pane glass? Is the frame aluminum, vinyl, or wood?

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question" since the OP has abandoned the question.

Comment: It looks to me that you have two separate problems....maybe some photos and more detailed explanations could help

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the door and the window are caulked all the way around the trim.

Sometimes painters neglect to caulk the tops of windows which eventually leads to leaks.

Comment: caulk wood or aluminium?